# spring bean creation time is too high

Tags: java, spring, time

I'm developing a game where is extremely critical how long algorithms work. And I noticed that if I create some @Prototype bean (which has only a few fields and getters setters) via the spring context it takes too much time compared with new object() case.

20 objects via new < 1ms.
20 objects via getBean() 5-10ms.

2000 objects via new < 1ms.
2000 objects via getBean() 209ms.

30000 objects via new = 2ms.
30000 objects via getBean() = 1407ms.

Is there some spring configuration for that which maybe I'm missing or do I need to rewrite my code to use new object() almost everywhere

Comment: Do you need the object to be spring managed? If not just create an instance yourself. Also make sure you are measuring the correct things, that `new` might not be as fast as you think due to the compiler optimizing things away if something isn't being used!.

Comment: I would suggest creating a factory bean (factory desing pattern) as a singleton, inject and use it to create your objects. You also could create your objects on thy fly, but with a factory the creation of objects still stays all in one place

Comment: I don't think you understand spring. It isn't meant for this use case. If you're writing a game, remove spring completely. In fact, java isn't the best language to use to write a game anyway, why not try C or C++?

Comment: it's a browser game and i'm java dev. i don't have 2-3 years to learn new language on the good level. that's why java. i don't need this object to be spring mantained but i saw lectures that devs should try to create all objects through spring

Comment: regarding factory there is also problems. i have a lot of creature actions and now i'm creating them through spring context by their name. it's just one line. in case of factory method there will be a switch case for 300+ cases. and moreover i will need to update this method everytime i'm adding new action. in case of spring it will be in context automatically because of @Component on new action class